# Compare 2 values between two position in a same file Linux

Tags: bash, shell

I have a large file of about 300K lines of records. In each line the value present in the position 60-74 should not repeat in same line of record. But at present it is getting repeated in same line between 84-98 position.

During processing due to this repetition of record the program just abruptly ends and couldn't able to print or identify quickly this line number or value in question.

In order to get a line number or value in question, I thought it can be done in 2 ways:

1. In every line take the value of position 60-74 and see if it is repeating in same line and if so print that line number.
2. Compare the columns COL1 (position 60-74) between COL2(84-98) and if matches print the line number.
   And I am trying to achieve this through one liner command since I cannot write up a script in production just to get a line number.

I tried following:

```
diff --width=30 --left-column --side-by-side <(cut -c60-74 file) <(cut -c84-98 file)
```

above is working for few cases but not working for all instances of problem.

Will add sample record soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'substr($0, 60, 15) != "               " && substr($0, 60, 15) == substr($0, 84, 15) { print NR }' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to skip if the position is empty .. Meaning if 60-74 is having spaces and 84-98 is also having spaces then it is still finding it as matching one.

Comment: Just add a check for that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a gawk, potentially also consider

```
gawk -e 'BEGIN { FS = "^.{59}[ ]{15}.{10}[ ]{15}." } NF > 1'
```

zero length lines have NF=0, and lines that failed to match will only have NF = 1. THis only works for the spaces cases. if you want a generic case, perhaps

```
gawk -e 'BEGIN{FS="^.{59}"} match($2,/^(.{15}).{10}(.{15})/,ar){

   if (ar[1]=arr[2]){print}}'
```

or even

```
gawk -F='^.{59}' -e 'index($2, substr($0,84,15))==1'
```